# Problem : Attribute int type vs varchar for product sorting showing no diffrence

Tags: product-attribute, sorting, magento-2.1.1

I have created Custom attribute for product sorting in magento 2.1.1. by Setup>installData.php `namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

```
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Resource\Eav\Attribute;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;


/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;
    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        /* assign object to class global variable for use in other class methods */
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
         $setup->startSetup();
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);


        /**
         * Add attributes to the eav/attribute
       */
       $eavSetup->addAttribute(
         \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
       'sorting_attribute',
       [
       'type' => 'int',
        'backend' => '',
        'frontend' => '',
        'label' => 'Sorting Attribute',
        'input' => 'text',
        'class' => '',
        'source' => '',
        'global' => 1,
        'visible' => true,
        'required' => false,
        'user_defined' => true,
        'default' => 0,
        'searchable' => false,
        'filterable' => false,
        'comparable' => false,
        'visible_on_front' => true,
        'used_in_product_listing' => true,
        'unique' => false,
        'apply_to' => 'simple,configurable,virtual,bundle,downloadable,grouped',
        'group'=> 'General'
       ]
      );






       $setup->endSetup();
    }
}`
```

Expected sorting for product

```
    Product a: custom_attribute = 12,
    Product b: custom_attribute = 42,
    Product c: custom_attribute = 55,
    Product d: custom_attribute = 135,
    Product e: custom_attribute = 325,
    Product f: custom_attribute = 443,
    Product g: custom_attribute = 1134,
    Product h: custom_attribute = 2231
```

but actually it is sorting as :

```
  Product a: custom_attribute = 443,
    Product b: custom_attribute = 135,
    Product c: custom_attribute = 325,
    Product d: custom_attribute = 55,
    Product e: custom_attribute = 42,
    Product f: custom_attribute = 1134,
    Product g: custom_attribute = 12,
    Product h: custom_attribute = 2231
```

After switching with other option and refreshing the page the sorting order gets changed , How it works ??
I tried with varchar type attribute created through admin it was also behaving very similar to the same.

[image]

Comment: Problem due to attribute type varchar. change it with int.

Comment: type is int only i said i tried  by creating one attribute from admin- varchar was showing same effect

Comment: something wrong with custom attribute, check directly it in table structure.

Comment: I have same issue,  changed it with int and it's working.

Comment: updated my ques with code what i have used where is the issue please check and help

Comment: can you add table structure screen shots from database.

Comment: backend type is varchar there ]

Comment: change it varchar  to int just for testing purpose. check it after change.

Comment: Where I can change this backend type?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48226/discussion-between-s-h-patel-and-supriya-mishra).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove these fields from the script

```
'backend' => '',
'frontend' => '',
```

after running setup:upgrade you will see backend_type is int in eav_attribute table.
Also add this in your script

```
'used_for_sort_by'=>1
```

After the attribute is created, do not save this attribute from admin because if you save it, backend_type will again change from int to varchar.